# Problema al almacenar datos en una BD con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una duda, cree un archivo en el cual uso un método php para almacenar información en una base de datos, en mi proyecto local me almacena los datos sin ningún problema, pero al subirlo a producción en un servidor en cpanel no los almacena ya que la variable **$res** siempre es negativa, ¿Alguna idea de qué podría ser?

Adjunto el archivo php.

```
<?php

// CONEXION A LA BD
$url = "localhost";
$usuario = "userejemplo";
$pass = "contraseñaejemplo";
$database = "baseejemplo";
$conexion = mysqli_connect("$url", "$usuario", "$pass", "$database");

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    die("Conexion fallida: " . $conexion->connect_error);
} 

$nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
$apellido = trim($_POST['apellido']);
$curso = trim($_POST['curso']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$telefono = trim($_POST['telefono']);

$query = "INSERT INTO interesados(nombre, apellido, curso, email, telefono) VALUES('$nombre', 
   '$apellido', '$curso', '$email', '$telefono')";

$res = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

if (!$res){
        echo "Hubo un error, intentelo de nuevo.<br><a href='index.html'>Volver al formulario.</a>";
} else {
        echo "Datos almacenados exitosamente.<br><a href='index.html'>Volver al formulario.</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Imprime `$res` y checkea que error te trae. Además imprime la consulta `$query` para revisar que no tengas errores de sintáxis

Comment: ¿Revisaste que la variables ```$url = "localhost";
$usuario = "userejemplo";
$pass = "contraseñaejemplo";
$database = "baseejemplo";``` esten correctas al subirlo al servidor?

Comment: despues del mysql_query, añade un `echo mysqli_error($conexion)` para ver que errores te ha dado mysql.